# Sort seaborn catplot by value counts within each facet

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sorting, seaborn, catplot

I am close but not quite there.  I am trying to sort an `sns.catplot` by value counts within each grouping.

Code and Output:

```
fig = plt.subplots(dpi=300)
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))

grid = sns.catplot(data=df, kind='count', y='violation_raw', row='stop_duration', height=4, aspect=3,
                   sharey=False, palette="dark:salmon_r",
                   order=df['violation_raw'].value_counts(ascending=False).index)

ax = grid.axes[0, 0]
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0])
ax = grid.axes[1, 0]
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0])
ax = grid.axes[2, 0]
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0])

plt.xlabel("Count", labelpad=12)

plt.margins(x=0.2)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

It is listing the rows in the exact same order per grouping, but they are not sorted by value counts within each grouping.

I want to sort, by `value_counts()` the rows in each respective grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is listing the rows in the exact same order per grouping, but they are not sorted by value counts within each grouping.

This is because `order` is currently set to the global value counts. I'm not sure it's possible to set a different `order` per facet.

One option is to pass the `groupby.value_counts()` directly as the `data` and plot the grouped counts with `kind='bar'`:

```
grid = sns.catplot(
    data=df.groupby('stop_duration')['violation_raw'].value_counts().reset_index(name='violation_count'),
    kind='bar', x='violation_count', y='violation_raw', row='stop_duration',
    height=4, aspect=3, sharey=False, palette='dark:salmon_r')

for ax in grid.axes.flat:
    ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0])
```

[image: counts sorted within groups]

Comment: That worked.  Much obliged.  I spent quite a bit of time trying a BUNCH of different things that all failed.